# Tap the text to show all of it

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I would like to create a ***See more...*** feature on the news feed, pretty much like Facebook. The SwiftUI list has rows, a row is composed of a VStack of (HStack (username, post time), Text (showing only 2 lines by default and expendable to show all of it is toggled) and finally an image with custom size. I was able to implement the toggle and set lineLimit to nil to reflect that but the problem is that the top HStack is outside the height of the row and hidden behind the previous row. I used a binding variable to trigger the views to refresh but ho results.

Comment: Maybe you could add some code of what you have done, or you could attach a link to your demo project.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: yes it did, thank you very much and sorry for the delay

Comment: no problem! make sure to upvote answers that helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working example of how you can achieve this with a `ScrollView` and a simple `struct` that represents the row:

```
import SwiftUI

struct FeedList: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(1...50, id: \.self) { item in
                VStack {
                    FeedRow()
                    Divider()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FeedRow: View {

    @State var value: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Username")
                Text("17:17h")
            }
            .padding(10)
            Text("I would like to create a See more... feature on the news feed, pretty much like Facebook. The SwiftUI list has rows, a row is composed of a VStack of (HStack (username, post time), Text (showing only 2 lines by default and expendable to show all of it is toggled) and finally an image with custom size. I was able to implement the toggle and set lineLimit to nil to reflect that but the problem is that the top HStack is outside the height of the row and hidden behind the previous row. I used a binding variable to trigger the views to refresh but ho results.")
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                .lineLimit(self.value ? nil : 2)
                .padding(.horizontal, 10)
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.value.toggle()
                    }
                }, label: {
                    if self.value {
                        Text("show less")
                    } else {
                        Text("show more")
                    }
                }).padding(.horizontal, 10)
            }
        }
        .animation(.easeInOut)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        FeedRow()
    }

}
```

It still has some issues, but I hope it helps!